# Histogram from csv file. Numeric data error

Tags: r, csv, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram from a single column with 454 rows. 
I keep getting a numeric data error. This is the code im running:

```
wr <- read.table("finance1_data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", as.is=TRUE)
hist(wr$AGG)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run str(wr) or class(wr$AGG), is the column you want to plot classed as a numeric? 

If you paste in the exact error that would also be helpful!

Comment: Running class(wr$AGG) yields "NULL" . Str(wr) shows the data frame containing 454 obs. of  1 variable.
The error I get is 'x' needs to be numeric, when running hist(wr$AGG).

Comment: OK, so try wr$AGG <- as.numeric(wr$AGG), and then re-run. I'm not sure why you would be getting NULL for the class to begin with!

Comment: I'm not sure either. From what I've seen others do, it seems so simple. Running wr$AGG <- as.numeric(wr$AGG) I get:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, AGG, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 454

Comment: It is, my best guess is that there is something wrong with your original dataset - I'm sorry, it's really frustrating for a new user! Can you try reading the data in with as.is  = FALSE? Hopefully numeric-looking data will automatically convert to numeric and problem solved!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the solution. The data file was saved as semicolon seperated file. While the code was sep=",".

Comment: Awesome, nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any data example, but with a standard .csv file with one column `Value` you can do something like quickly with `tidyverse`/`ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- read_csv("sample.csv")

ggplot(test, aes(Value)) + geom_histogram(bins = 5, fill = "red")
```

[image]